# How can I run a JavaScript function with any click on the page?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I'm using `<body onload="function">`, which changes some text on the page based on which element is focused on. It works fine, but I need my site to run the function every time the focus changes (or, even better, every time any part of the page is clicked).

Currently the code looks like this:

```
<body onload="changeText()">
<script>
function changeText(){
     function here;
}
</script>
<p>This is where text changes based on the function</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think he's asking what to hook the `onclick` to.

Comment: Why are people down voting this legitimate question?

Comment: @RASG so what, same goes for an extremely high percentage of most of the questions on SO, including the ones with high votes. Searching SO I couldn't find a similar question. And that is what matters.

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos `Searching SO I couldn't find a similar question. And that is what matters.` oh really? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521487/javascript-body-onclick , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152802/body-onclick-doesnt-work-but-the-onclick-works-when-attached-to-a-a-tag , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762472/body-onclick-go-to-textarea

Comment: @RASG awesome & +1 for you! btw I found that first one too, you must of really searched hard for those or not; you just know of the `onclick` event where as sway doesn't. The 2nd SO link is the best but if you have no idea what onclick is to begin with this question's title is better for the beginner. I wouldn't consider the 1st link related, especially to a beginner. The 3rd is close but still for a beginner is not obvious especially with textarea in the title.

Answer (score 8):

You can attach onclick event on document. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmHuZ/3/)

```
​document.onclick = function(){
 // your code
 //alert("clicked");
}​
```

If you want change on focus then use

```
window.onfocus = function(){

   // your code
     //alert("focus");
}
```

Comment: This method will also disable every other normal click event on the page. Example http://jsfiddle.net/5TVAm/1/

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos Why do you think it will disable other click event. both are separated example I showed in one. changing body html is just to show that focus got called. OP will use it differently.

Comment: ok to be fair and to be clear: the `window.onfocus` function will overide normal click events. document.onclick will not. Example http://jsfiddle.net/6qKyq/1/

Comment: @Shusl Directly setting `.onclick` overwrites any other previously bound click events. Using something like `addEventListener` actually adds a new event.

Comment: @ianpgall, no it will not happen as first click event will be listen by element clicked not document. it will reach to document only if propagation of click is not stopped.

Comment: @Shusl What I'm saying is that if somewhere else previously in the code, in an external library uses `.onclick`, then your call will overwrite that. I'm not talking about propagation from nested elements, but the fact that you're setting the attribute, not truly binding an event (the "right" way)

Comment: @Shusl I believe @ianpgall is talking about `document.onclick = myCustomFunction();` will be overwritten by a second call to `document.onclick = mySecondCustomFunction();` (if there is one that exists)

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos, I don't think your changes will work on all browsers. second there are very rare chance to use window.onclick or document.onclick at more than one places. and problem you highlighted in example is because I am changing html of body on focus of window I dont think OP going to use this way.

Answer (score 3):

```js
window.onclick = function () {
  //do some stuff
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<p>text text text</p>
<button>it does not matters if you press me or any where else</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<body onload="changeText()">
<script>
function changeText(){
    function here;
}
document.onclick=function(){changeText();};
</script>
<p>This is where text changes based on the function</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't suffer from the disable-clicking issue

```
$(document).click(function(e){
                //Blah
            })
```